# Why do pure Typescript projects include .d.ts definitions?

Tags: typescript

Why do Typescript projects include .d.ts definitions... seems counter productive?

If a library is already developed in TypeScript (like Angular2 let's say), and the TS transpiler can use the source .ts files for intellisence, why do I keep seeing in TS projects .d.ts file being included?

Now sure you can easily generate .d.ts definition via the tsd executable, but I can't see the logic.

regards,

Sean

Comment: the compilation (or transpilation if you prefere) of a ts source project has the following output 1) A js file (or several) that are just plain es5 js file 2) a .d.ts  definition file that describes the type constraints of the original project (lost in the transpilation to js). The second file is used for type checking and autocomplete when using a compiled (js + .d.ts) project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes down to distribution. Referencing a project via npm/bower provides a "main" file that is javascript, not typescript. As such, it makes most sense for the compilation output of a Typescript project to be:

a) The transpiled javascript file, possibly minified

b) A .d.ts file describing the type annotations (kind of like a header file in C)

It wouldn't make much sense to distribute in typescript since it either would prevent javascript projects from using it, or would necessitate a separate typescript version of the npm package.

Comment: I understand now, the C header example is pretty good actually, basically just exposing the interfaces... I for one would also want to see the TypeScript source, not just the header files (.d.ts) but I guess that's what Github is for... tx again, good answer!